# Finding a function for biomass as response variable

Tags: experiment-design, gradient-descent, function

I would like to know how I would go about systematically finding an analytical function for biomass growth.

I have a plant production facility with lots of sensors and variables to tweek, but I need an actual function to find the optimal - say with *gradient descent*.

The function will be something like this:

x1+x2+x3...xn =y

where y is the biomass and x1..xn are the variables affecting the biomass e.g. light intensitiy, humidity, carbon dioxide concentration, nutrient concentration etc.

Any ideas of where to start? How difficult could it be?

Comment: This sounds like you might be looking for *response surface methodology*: please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology.

Comment: You can posit almost any kind of relationship you want.  There is a danger in making the model too flexible: it can actually become *less* accurate by "overfitting" the data.  Evidently this is an art and a science, so a general answer could not be given in any reasonably small space.  I am aware of related methods, such as the use of kriging in an effort to minimize the sample size, and I'm sure there are many others I don't know about.

Comment: I think this is a great start. I will look into RSM some more. I'm actually doing experimental design and will receive data points for a set of variables. My initial thought was to use experimental design and later on gradient descent but I could not find any analytical function (using the variables Im interested in)! In other words I have to start "from scratch" finding the relationship between the explanatory variables and the response variable.

Comment: Note that commonly the *goal* of an experimental design is to allow reliable estimation of response surface parameters (i.e. the optimal design may vary depending on the [surrogate model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_model)).